# Select only one checkbox in a group

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I have a lot of the same `<div class="checkbox product-option">`, where each four div's do belong to each other.

So 1-4 is a group, 5-8 is a group etc.

Is there a way to allow only 1 checkbox in a group to be selected?

I currently have this code, but that works for all checkbox and not for a group of four.

jQuery:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function() {
   $('input[type="checkbox"]').not(this).prop('checked', false);
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="checkbox product-option">
    <label for="addon1">
        <span class="product-option-text">
            <input class="checkbox-row" type="checkbox" name="addons[1]" id="addon1" onclick="prodconfrecalcsummary()">
            <span class="text">Text</span>
        </span>
    </label>
</div>

<div class="checkbox product-option">
    <label for="addon11">
        <span class="product-option-text">
            <input class="checkbox-row" type="checkbox" name="addons[11]" id="addon1" onclick="prodconfrecalcsummary()">
            <span class="text">Text</span>
        </span>
    </label>
</div>

<div class="checkbox product-option">
    <label for="addon12">
        <span class="product-option-text">
            <input class="checkbox-row" type="checkbox" name="addons[21]" id="addon1" onclick="prodconfrecalcsummary()">
            <span class="text">Text</span>
        </span>
    </label>
</div>

<div class="checkbox product-option">
    <label for="addon54">
        <span class="product-option-text">
            <input class="checkbox-row" type="checkbox" name="addons[54]" id="addon1" onclick="prodconfrecalcsummary()">
            <span class="text">Text</span>
        </span>
    </label>
</div>
```

Comment: It sounds like you should be using radio buttons rather than checkboxes.

Comment: Users have expectations when it comes to form controls and making checkboxes behave like radio buttons isn't a good idea. Also, IDs **must** be unique.

Comment: why don't you use a radio button group instead of checkboxes

Comment: Do you have control over the generated HTML or is it spit out like you show? And if the latter, do the `.product-option` divs have any distinguishing classes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you only want one item to be selectable in each group, then you should use radio buttons rather than checkboxes. Then users will expect and understand that only one item is selectable. And if you create a series of radio buttons with the same "name" attribute, then the browser will automatically only allow one of them to be selected.

If you use checkboxes, then even if you use javascript to achieve what you suggest, then your users are likely to be confused, as the normal use of checkboxes is to allow the selection of multiple items at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use id for select and then change your jquery code
`$('#yourIdHere').on('change', function() {
   //Whatever your code...
});`

Answer (score 0):

Is this? Put the css selector

```
$('input[type="checkbox"].checkbox.product-option').on('change', function() {
    $('input[type="checkbox"].checkbox.product-option').not(this).prop('checked', false);
});
```

Is the same code, but with css selector.